# WS - get instance id from worker_groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

How to get instance id from this configuration?

```
  worker_groups = [
    {
      name                          = "model-service_worker-group-1"
      instance_type                 = "p3.2xlarge"
      additional_userdata           = "echo foo bar"
      asg_desired_capacity          = 1
      additional_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.worker_group_mgmt_one.id]
    },
```

i'd like to reuse this instance and attach EBS to it:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "this_ec2" {
  count = 1

  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = "0a7e25357443b6df0"
  instance_id = <INSTANCE ID HERE>
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "this" {
  count = 1

  availability_zone = module.eks.availability_zone[count.index]
  size              = 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such information as instances id is not provided by [terraform-aws-eks](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks) module. This is because it uses AutoScaling Group (ASG) to managed your worker instances. The instances in ASG **are outside of TF control**. Thus, you can't get their ids.

At best you would have to design a **custom solution** to get current instances in asg. This could be possible, as `terraform-aws-eks` outputs `workers_asg_arns`. But its still poor design, as instances in ASG can be replaced at any time without any involvement of your TF code. This will **lead to failures** in the long term, if you rely on the instances to be always same.